# How do I decrease the vertical spacing between the html elements in my dot grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to decrease the vertical height between elements of my dot grid within **@media screen and (max-width: 425px)**.

[image]

How would I accomplish this on my dynamic grid?
So far I've attempted to decrease the cell height, and that wasn't successful. A example of my CSS attempt is below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
         .cell {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
          grid-gap: 0;
          height: 5px;
         }
      }
```

Here is the current status of my project:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .header-wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .custom-uw {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .circles {
        display: grid !important;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
        min-height: 0;
        grid-gap: 0px 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cell {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 2px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .circles {
            display: grid !important;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
            min-height: 0;
            grid-gap: 0px 13px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .circles {
            display: grid !important;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
            min-height: 0;
            grid-gap: 2px 6px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .cell {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 0;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
        .circles {
            display: grid !important;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
            min-height: 0;
            grid-gap: 0px 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .cell {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 0;
        }
    }

    .cell i {
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-color: white;
    }

    .circles {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-uw">
        <div class="circles"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let grid_columns;
        let differential;

        checkWindowWidth();

        const cellCircles = 3;
        createCircles();
        const circles = document.querySelector('.circles');
        let circleChildren = circles.childNodes;
        let grid_rows = circleChildren.length / grid_columns;
        center_row = Math.ceil(grid_rows / 2);

        const color1 = randomColor().color1;
        const color2 = randomColor().color2;

        circleChildren.forEach((element) => {
            element.childNodes.forEach((element) => {
                element.style.backgroundColor = color2;
            });
        });

        window.onresize = checkWindowWidth;
        window.onresize = createCircles;
        window.onresize = circleGridArray;

        function checkWindowWidth() {
            // if 768 or less 8 grid columns
            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                grid_columns = 14;
                differential = 0;
            } else {
                grid_columns = 14;
                differential = 10;
            }
        }

        function createCircles() {
            let headerHeight = document.querySelector('.header-wrapper').offsetHeight;
            let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
            let heroHeight = viewportHeight - headerHeight;
            let hero = document.querySelector('.custom-uw');
            hero.style.height = `${heroHeight}px`;

            const circles = document.querySelector('.circles');
            circles.innerHTML = '';
            // define circles grid inner html as empty
            const cellWidth = circles.offsetWidth / grid_columns;
            // cell width is determined by number of columns
            let cellHeight = (cellWidth - differential) / cellCircles;

            const rows = Math.floor(hero.offsetHeight / cellHeight);
            let html = '';
            let cell = '<div class="cell">';
            for (let i = 0; i < cellCircles; i++) {
                cell += '<i></i>';
            }
            cell += '</div>';
            for (let i = 0; i < grid_columns * rows; i++) {
                html += cell;
            }

            circles.innerHTML = html;
        }

        function circleGridArray() {
            let gridArr = [];
            let row = [];

            circleChildren.forEach((element) => {
                if (row.length == grid_columns) {
                    gridArr.push(row);
                    row = [];
                    row.push(element);
                } else if (row.length < grid_columns) {
                    row.push(element);
                    if (row.length == grid_columns) {
                        gridArr.push(row);
                        row = [];
                    }
                }
            });
            return gridArr;
        }

        let testArr = circleGridArray();



        function filling(arr, left_circle, center_circle, right_circle) {
            let rules = [left_circle, center_circle, right_circle];

            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                let element = arr[i];
                let rule = rules[i];

                if (rule) {
                    element.style.backgroundColor = color1;
                }
            }
        }

        function randomColor() {
            let color1 = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };
            let color2 = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 };

            while (true) {
                // Generate two random colors
                color1.r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 192);
                color1.g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 192);
                color1.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 192);
                color2.r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64) + 128;
                color2.g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64) + 128;
                color2.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64) + 128;

                // Check if the color is not too dark or too light
                if (color1.r + color1.g + color1.b > 400 || color1.r + color1.g + color1.b < 200) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if the color is not too neon
                if (Math.max(color1.r, color1.g, color1.b) - Math.min(color1.r, color1.g, color1.b) > 90) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if the difference in luminance between color1 and color2 is enough to increase legibility
                const color1Luminance = 0.3126 * color1.r + 0.8152 * color1.g + 0.0822 * color1.b;
                const color2Luminance = 0.3126 * color2.r + 0.8152 * color2.g + 0.0822 * color2.b;
                const luminanceDifference = color2Luminance - color1Luminance;
                if (luminanceDifference < 0 || luminanceDifference < 0.4) {
                    continue;
                }

                break;
            }

            return {
                color1: `rgb(${color1.r}, ${color1.g}, ${color1.b})`,
                color2: `rgb(${color2.r}, ${color2.g}, ${color2.b})`,
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the number of rows defined by calculation? Are you saying you want more rows? And a cell is a little row of 3 dots, I can't see that altering the grid gap of that has anything to do with the vertical spacing.

Comment: You could give the dots you want to move a negative margin, for instance: `margin-top: -10px`;

Comment: When the page is loaded, the JS sets the "hero" height via `hero.style.height = `${heroHeight}px`;` `<div class="custom-uw" style="height: 163px;">` If the viewport size is reduced by not reloaded, the grid is stretched to fill the previous height because the `custom-uw` class applies `display: flex`